# JQuery autocomplete is only working for the first input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to have three input that display a list of lodging that march the search term

My HTML goes like this:

```
<p>
    <input id="lowgradeLogding" class="lodgingCombo"/>
    <input id="lowgradeLogdingId"/>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="midgradeLodging" class="lodgingCombo"/>
    <input id="midgradeLodgingId"/>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="higradeLodging" class="lodgingCombo"/>
    <input id="higradeLodgingId"/>
</p>
```

And my javascript is

```
<script>
    $(".lodgingCombo").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Data/SearchProducts', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                data: { query: request.term },
                success: function (data) { response(data); }
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.ProductName);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.ProductName);                
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a><div>" + item.ProductName + "<br>" + item.EstablishmentName + "</div></a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
</script>
```

The autocomplete drop down only appears on the first input (lowgradeLodging). On the others it display a small artifact that look like an empty dropdown.

How can I make all three input work with the autocomplete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$('.lodgingCombo')` selector is returning a collection and you're only running `autocomplete` on the first item.  You need to use `each` to run it on every element returned by the selector

```
$(".lodgingCombo").each(function() { 
  $(this).autocomplete({
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Superbe, I'm still learning javascript and jquery and I though it was applied to all the result of the selector.

Comment: @Pierre-Alain still learning myself. Takes a bit to get your head around but once you do it's really quite elegant.