# autocomplete only working for first input field

Tags: ajax, autocomplete

I am trying to get autocomplete working on any div with the id="train" however, it seems to only be working on the first input field with a class of "train"

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".train").each(function() {
        $(".train").keyup(function() {
        $("#suggest_q").html("");
            var train = $(".train").val();  
            train = $.trim(train);
            if(train)
            {
                $.ajax({

                    url: "train_ajax_query.php",
                    data: "train="+train,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $("#suggest_q").html(msg);
                        $("#suggest_q ul li").mouseover(function() {
                            $("#suggest_q ul li").removeClass("hover");
                            $(this).addClass("hover");
                        })
                        $("#suggest_q ul li").click(function() {
                            var value   =   $(this).html();
                            $("#train").val(value);
                            $("#suggest_q ul li").remove();
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

});

</script>
```

HTML code:

```
    <form id="train_create_form" name="train" action="submit_train.php" method="POST">


    <input type="text" id="train" class="train" size="20" name="train[]" placeholder="Train 1" />
        <div id="suggest_q">

        </div>
    <input type="text" id="train" size="20" class="train" name="train[]" placeholder="Train 2" />
        <div id="suggest_q">

        </div>

  <input id= "submit_train" type="submit" name="submit_train" value="Submit All trains">
        </form>
```

I found [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249818/jquery-autocomplete-is-only-working-for-the-first-input) but I am not sure how to adopt the fix for my problem :(

add more input fields code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 0;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><input type="text" id="train" name="train[]" class="train" placeholder="Train ' + i +'" /><div id="suggest_q"></div><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove train</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The value of an ID should be unique (as per [**spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)). "id = name , This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beause here:

```
    $(".train").each(function() {
        $(".train").keyup(function() {
```

you get every time only first field :) try:

```
    $(".train").each(function(index, element) {
        element.keyup(function() {
            // or even: $(element).keyup(function() {
```

References:
[Each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
[KeyUp](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)
[Val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

I copypaste whole example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".train").each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).keyup(function() {
        $("#suggest_q").html("");
            var train = $(element).val();   
            train = $.trim(train);
            if(train)
            {
                $.ajax({

                    url: "train_ajax_query.php",
                    data: "train="+train,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $("#suggest_q").html(msg);
                        $("#suggest_q ul li").mouseover(function() {
                            $("#suggest_q ul li").removeClass("hover");
                            $(this).addClass("hover");
                        })
                        $("#suggest_q ul li").click(function() {
                            var value   =   $(this).html();
                            $(element).val(value);
                            $("#suggest_q ul li").remove();
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I am sorry Anton, bit idk what you mean... should I remove those two lines?

Comment: No, replace $(".train").each(function() { with $(".train").each(function(index, element) { and  $(".train").keyup(function() { with $(element).keyup(function() {

Comment: Anton, I tried that code and now the script wont produce the autocomplete for the first one either... any other suggestions?

Comment: I edit my answer. Look in browser/firebug console for errors.

Comment: Anton, NICE THAT worked for the two input fields but anything after that is doesn't work. I updated my question with code to show how I am allowing the user to add more input fields if they choose.

Comment: @user1725473 - Don't forget about the duplicate id's we talked about. That *will* come back to haunt you later. ;)

Comment: @user1725473: if you create new elements you should also attach keyup listeners ;)

Comment: lol right! i just removed them but it still wont work for the input fields beyond the initial two....     Anton, how would I attach keyup listeners? would they be added to the input html fields?

Comment: Try to replace $(".train").keyup(function() { with $(".train").live("keyup", function() { See http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Each time you type `$(".train")`, you're searching again for all the elements.

Once you've done your initial `$(".train").each(function() {` line, you can just use $(this) to refer to the element, and that function will get called on each element.

When you use `var train = $(".train").val();` you are getting just the value of the first element.  See http://api.jquery.com/val/ for more details on why.

If you remove that line and just use `$(this)` instead of '''train''' this should work better, but you will also want to get rid of the .each() around the .keyup(), since `$(".train").keyup` will already apply to all matching elements.

You're basically saying "go through and find all train elements.  For each one, go through and set the keyup value on all train elements.  Set it to a function which enforces autocomplete on the first train element".  You want to be saying "Set the keyup callback on each train elements to enforce autocomplete on itself"